# Reverse Proxy login with credentials from node.js

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, shiro

I currently have a server running Spring in a Tomcat servlet with Shiro Token system for checking if a user is logged in already. It allows cross-domain requests.

In any other domain I can on the client (generally using angular) call...

`http.get('https://<my_check_login_service>', {withCredentials: true})`

...and as long as I am already logged in (token doesn't expire) return the user info (name, avatar, etc.).

I have another system now that is a node server (also serving up angular for the client side) for which I would like to call the node server and have it proxy over to the above **my_check_login_service** to get the user, set info on the session object (using express), and then return the user to the client. But also, through the session object, allow me to trust their connection and allow them to perform further api calls depending on the security level of the user returned from the login service.

On the node.js router I can proxy doing this ...

```
app.get('/checklogin', function(req, res) {
    req.pipe(request.get("https://<my_check_login_service>").pipe(res);
}
```

...but I don't know how to pass the proper credentials to the service. If I do ...

`http.get('checkLogin', {withCredentials: true})`

...it, of course, doesn't work because the credentials for my login_service are not sent to the local server. How can I pass the correct credentials to make this work?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credentials are most likely in the HTTP headers, passing all headers (both from request and to response), with the address of original request, should make it work:

```
app.get('/checklogin', function(req, res) {
  console.dir(req.headers)
  //You can inspect the headers here and pass only required values
  const options = {
    url: 'https://<my_check_login_service>',
    headers: Object.assign(
      //Tell the login service about address of original request
      {'X-Forwarded-For': req.connection.remoteAddress}
      req.headers)
  }
  req.pipe(request.get(options))
  .on('response', (response) => res.set(response.headers))
  .pipe(res)
}
```

This example passes original address by setting `X-Forwarded-For`, `login_service` may recognize it ...or not, depending on the configuration.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I'm not *entirely* sure it will work because I now realize that I probably need a wildcard certificate to make it work for me. But with this change I now get "Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames:..." I'm assuming a wildcard cert will fix this right up. Will update this when I get that squared away.

Comment: `login_service` also checks client IP address, so the proxy should pass it.
I'm adding that to the answer

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. Adding the headers at least let the server know some information but does not pass the security tokens required to login. I think what I want to do is impossible and I just have to implement an OAuth system. If I get no other answers before the bounty expires I'll give it to you for sure.  Thank you. :)

Comment: "Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames:..." looks like SSL error. Are you using same hostname&port when doing request to `<my_check_login_service>` from nodejs server as you are using from the client (angular) e.g. not swapping domain name with some local IP on the node server? The other thing I'd suggest to try in the script above is to delete `Host` header from both `options.headers` (assuming nodejs will fill in the correct one from the login request URL) since now it looks like you are passing your nodejs server host to login server and that might confuse SSL check.

Comment: Yes using same domain name in server code as I have on the client. Are you suggesting that I try with a local IP address?